# take everything from a branch regardless of conflicts and other changes

Tags: git, merge

I am doing a GIT merge and have got conflicts and merges on the branch I am merging to.

Consider 
    branch A with code from last week
    branch B with code from today

I want to merge branchB into branchA. If there are conflicts I want to take that from branchB. If there are any file changes (auto-merge) I want to ignore them and again take from branchB

Is there a way I can go through the files can force all files that have changed on branchA to have the contents of the files on branchB?

Git merged by commits and not files so I am not sure if this is possible. Otherwise I'll do a compare and have to compare and replace each file. (there are >1000 eekk!)

Thanks

**Edit**
Thanks for the comment @AndrewC. I want the opposite of ours I think. From the documentation

> ours - This resolves any number of heads, but the result of the merge
>   is always the current branch head. It is meant to be used to supersede
>   old development history of side branches.

I will be on branchA and want to merge in branchB and keep all branchB files. I think using ours merge strategy will keep all of branchA files

Comment: look at the man page for git merge and check out strategy=ours

Comment: Thanks @AndrewC I'll update the question with my comment

Comment: You do **not** want the ours *strategy*.  The ours strategy does not resolve conflicts, it takes the ours side wholesale and ignores any changes made in theirs (conflicting changes or not).

Comment: In that case you want the opposite then which is the "theirs" strategy.

Answer (score 0):

The merge would not have conflicts if branch A files hadn't changed between when you last cloned / fetched / pulled unless they had changed, so are you sure you want to overwrite with branch B's files?

If you do want to overwrite, when you perform your merge and do a git status for conflicts, you want everything from branch B, right? Why not write a little bash to checkout everything in the git status from branch B?

Essentially read in all the file paths from the git status and do:

```
git checkout <branch_b_name> /path/to/file
```